# How to remove the file from trash in drive in colab

Tags: python, google-drive-api, google-colaboratory

I use a [google drive in colab](https://colab.research.google.com/notebooks/io.ipynb#scrollTo=u22w3BFiOveA). Basically I do the following:

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/gdrive')
```

After this I can use `os` function (`listdir`, `remove`) to manipulate the files. The problem is that after removing the file with `os.remove` it is not actually removed but goes to trash. I would like to remove a file completely but up till now I have not found how to do this.

I tried to locate the file in a trash but the trash directory shows nothing `os.listdir('/content/gdrive/.Trash')` also I see the files there in the web interface.

How can I remove the file from trash?

Comment: use google drive api `Files:delete` https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/files/delete#examples

Comment: I had the same problem with model files I was storing in Google Drive. Eventually I found the process of deleting these files from the trash was very convoluted, so I decided to overwrite the files instead. In my case this is an option, since I am training models in a loop, and the models names are the same in each loop.

Answer (score 11):

It is straightforward to perform this action inside Google Colab by using the [pydrive](https://pythonhosted.org/PyDrive/index.html) module. In order to delete all files from your Google Drive's Trash folder, code the following lines in your Google Colab notebook:

```
from pydrive.auth import GoogleAuth
from pydrive.drive import GoogleDrive
from google.colab import auth
from oauth2client.client import GoogleCredentials

auth.authenticate_user()
gauth = GoogleAuth()
gauth.credentials = GoogleCredentials.get_application_default()
my_drive = GoogleDrive(gauth)
```

After entering authentication code and creating a valid instance of GoogleDrive class, write:

```
for a_file in my_drive.ListFile({'q': "trashed = true"}).GetList():
    # print the name of the file being deleted.
    print(f'the file "{a_file['title']}", is about to get deleted permanently.')
    # delete the file permanently.
    a_file.Delete()
```

If you'd like to delete a specific file in Trash, then you need to change the last chunck of code. Let's assume you have a file which is named `weights-improvement-01-10.5336.hdf5` in your Trash:

```
for a_file in my_drive.ListFile({'q': "title = 'weights-improvement-01-10.5336.hdf5' and trashed=true"}).GetList():
    # print the name of the file being deleted.
    print(f'the file "{a_file['title']}", is about to get deleted permanently.')    
    # delete the file permanently.
    a_file.Delete()
```

If you want to make other and perhaps more complex queries, e.g. delete a bunch of files which have the expression `weights-improvement-` in common in their names, or files all of which have been modified before a given date; visit: 
1) [Get all files which matches the query](https://pythonhosted.org/PyDrive/filelist.html#get-all-files-which-matches-the-query),
2) [Search for files and folders](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/search-files).

Answer (score 4):

Jess's answer of using Google Drive API to clear the trash isn't a good way because you might actually have other data in the bin

Because files will move to bin upon delete, so this neat trick reduces the file size to 0 before deleting (cannot be undone!)

```py
import os

delete_filepath = 'drive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/somefolder/examplefile.png'

open(delete_filename, 'w').close() #overwrite and make the file blank instead - ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4914288/3553367
os.remove(delete_filename) #delete the blank file from google drive will move the file to bin instead
```

Also answered at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60729089/3553367

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for a code for removing the file from the trash, you can check this SO post answered by Tanaike - [Empty Google Drive Trash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48820510/empty-google-drive-trash-with-python):

```
def main():
    credentials = get_credentials()
    http = credentials.authorize(httplib2.Http())     
    service = discovery.build('drive', 'v3', http=http)
    service.files().emptyTrash().execute()
```

or use these [methods using Pydrive](https://pythonhosted.org/PyDrive/filemanagement.html#delete-trash-and-un-trash-files):

```
file.Trash() - Move file to trash
file.Untrash() - Move file out of trash
file.Delete() - Permanently delete the file
```

Answer (score 0):

We can run these codes in google colab successfully:

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/root/gdrive', force_remount=True)

from google.colab import auth
auth.authenticate_user()
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
drive_service = build('drive', 'v3')
drive_service.files().emptyTrash().execute()
```

but if there're many files in the google drive trash bin, we still need to wait for over 20 minutes, sad.

The rclone command has a immediate effect:

```
!curl https://rclone.org/install.sh | bash
!rclone config    # to set google drive client id etc

#delete all files in trash and don't put them in trash again:
!rclone --config /root/sing/rclone.conf delete gdrive: --drive-trashed-only --drive-use-trash=false
!rclone --config /root/sing/rclone.conf ls gdrive: --drive-trashed-only --fast-list
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to permanently delete files for google drive is the `rm` command.
You can delete a specific file using `rm`:

```
!rm /content/drive/MyDrive/somefolder/examplefile.png
```

Or, you can delete a whole folder:

```
!rm -r /content/drive/MyDrive/somefolder
```

Or, you can use wildcards for deleting files with specific patterns:

```
!rm /content/drive/MyDrive/somefolder/*.png
```

However, if you want to delete files from trash, you have to use google drive API.